# read_table read all data to one column

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I got a file like this:

```
TCGA1 0 QWE
TCGA2 1 QWE
TCGA2 -2 RAF
TCGA3 2 KLS
```

and tried to read it into a dataframe using pandas.

```
In [16]: df = pd.read_table('TR.txt',header=None)
```

but the result showed like this:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
          0
0   TCGA1 0 QWE
1   TCGA2 1 QWE
2  TCGA2 -2 RAF
3   TCGA3 2 KLS
```

Column names has been missed, and how could I solve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `sep='s\+'` for separator arbitrary whitespace in [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html).

It does not work as you expected, because default separator is `,`, so all data are in one column.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""TCGA1 0 QWE
TCGA2 1 QWE
TCGA2 -2 RAF
TCGA3 2 KLS"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header=None)
print df
       0  1    2
0  TCGA1  0  QWE
1  TCGA2  1  QWE
2  TCGA2 -2  RAF
3  TCGA3  2  KLS
```

Another solution with parameter `delim_whitespace=True`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""TCGA1 0 QWE
TCGA2 1 QWE
TCGA2 -2 RAF
TCGA3 2 KLS"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
print df
       0  1    2
0  TCGA1  0  QWE
1  TCGA2  1  QWE
2  TCGA2 -2  RAF
3  TCGA3  2  KLS
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have ignored this before.